# Get the ranking just with COUNT(ID) and using having

Tags: mysql, ranking, having

I've a query in which I get the ranking of an user.

The table looks like this (here is order by points):

```
-----------------
| user | points |
-----------------
  paul1   22000
  paul    13440
  paul5    1400
  paul2    1300
  paul3    1300
  paul4    1300
   .        .
   .        .
   .        .

SELECT user, points
FROM table1 
WHERE points>= 1300 
HAVING user <= 'paul3' OR points > 1300 
ORDER BY points DESC, user ASC
```

This query returns the correct data I need but I really need only the number of rows (5 in this example), so I tried modifying the query as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS num, user, points
FROM table1 
WHERE points>= 1300 
HAVING user <= 'paul3' OR points > 1300 
ORDER BY points DESC, user ASC
```

But here it returns num = 6 and I don't understand at all why.

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using both a `where` and a `having` clause with no aggregation?  Your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT user, points
FROM table1 
WHERE (user <= 'paul3' and points = 1300) OR (points > 1300) 
ORDER BY points DESC, user ASC
```

If you want to count the rows, then just do `count(*)` in the `select`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1 
WHERE (user <= 'paul3' and points = 1300) OR (points > 1300) 
ORDER BY points DESC, user ASC;
```

The reason your query doesn't do what you want is because the `having` clause is evaluated *after* the aggregation.  It filters the result of the aggregation, not of the rows going into the aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Try counting all distinct users:

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS num
FROM table1 
WHERE points>= 1300 
HAVING user <= 'paul3' OR points > 1300 
ORDER BY points DESC, user ASC
```